# Why is this while loop only running once then freezing until the result task is complete? Blazor Server c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous, blazor

I have the following Blazor Server code that calls an async Task which is not awaited, but instead uses a while loop to check for the completion or exception of the task. The issue I'm having is that the while loop only appears to run once, and then seems to just stop. The task is not faulted and is not complete, but once it does complete, it exits the while loop and continues as expected.

Can anyone shed some light on what going on here?

```
    private async Task Generate()
    {
        awaitingRequest = true;
        StateHasChanged();

        var result = gPT.SendCommand("system", bot.Description, apiKey, true);

        try
        {
            loopCount = 0;
            while (!result.IsCompleted && !result.IsFaulted)
            {
                //Update the UI after the asynchronous operation
                await Task.Delay(500);               

                loopCount++;

                StateHasChanged();
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
        }

        outputText = gPT.messages[1].content;
        awaitingRequest = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

I have tried various breakpoints and have bound loopCount to a textarea control to visual confirmation, both just indicate that it stops in the while loop after calling await Task.Delay(500) for the second time. I tried setting ConfigureAwait(false) but it made no difference. I basically want to eh UI to be updating whilst the gPT.SendCommand method is running. I have used this approach before and its worked fine, so I am at a loss as to what is causing it.

Comment: Your return type is `async void`. Change it to `async Task`

Comment: I've been caught out by this one before, it's an easy mistake to make

Comment: Hold up, do you mean the whole method is not being awaited? If so, you have no feedback when an exception occurs. Try adding some error handling and put a breakpoint to confirm you're not getting an unhandled exception

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Tried changing it to Task, but the problem still persists. Also the result task has its own error checking and does complete all ok (after about 10 seconds). The while loop just seems to hang and then start going again when the result task actually does finish?

Comment: Have also added a try-catch for this section and nothing is being caught.

Comment: What's the loop doing?  The code is calling `StateHassChanged` without mutating the state.  Also there's no context to the code.  Who's calling `Generate`?

Comment: It looks like it was because the Task was still using the same thread. Calling it from inside Task.Run seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: _"Task which is not awaited, but instead uses a while loop to check for the completion or exception of the task"_ - omg, _why_? Why would you do that?

Comment: ^^ Just start a timer that ticks every 500ms and updates the UI, then await the Task, then stop the timer. Done.

Comment: Because there is no need to introduce the extra overhead of a timer in this situation.

Comment: Overhead? That's about 3 lines of code ...

Comment: Code amount != overhead. Why import a class when its not needed?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue was that gPT.SendCommand, although an async Task, was not running on its own thread. Using Task.Run has fixed the issue. Perhaps someone can confirm this.

```
 var result = Task.Run(async () => await gPT.SendCommand("system", bot.Description, apiKey, true));
```

---

#### Explanation

- The `Generate()` method is called. It starts running on the UI thread.
- The `SendCommand()` method is called by `Generate()`. The task is queued on the UI thread (the same thread as the parent method).
- The `Generate()` method goes through the first iteration of the *while* loop and calls `await Task.Delay(500)`, yielding the thread.
- The UI thread starts working through any other tasks in its queue
- The `SendCommand` task is picked up
- The `SendCommand` task does not yield until it is completed

  - This suggests it is polling for a response rather than using asynchronous IO
- Once it is completed, the UI thread continues working through the tasks in its queue and comes back to the `Generate` task

Stephen Toub describes a similar situation in his [article about ConfigureAwait](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/):

> Consider a library method that uses await on the result of some network download. You invoke this method and synchronously block waiting for it to complete, such as by using .Wait() or .Result or .GetAwaiter().GetResult() off of the returned Task object. Now consider what happens if your invocation of it happens when the current SynchronizationContext is one that limits the number of operations that can be running on it to 1, whether explicitly via something like the MaxConcurrencySynchronizationContext shown earlier, or implicitly by this being a context that only has one thread that can be used, e.g. a UI thread. So you invoke the method on that one thread and then block it waiting for the operation to complete. The operation kicks off the network download and awaits it. Since by default awaiting a Task will capture the current SynchronizationContext, it does so, and when the network download completes, it queues back to the SynchronizationContext the callback that will invoke the remainder of the operation. But the only thread that can process the queued callback is currently blocked by your code blocking waiting on the operation to complete. And that operation won’t complete until the callback is processed. Deadlock!

##### Why does `ConfigureAwait(false)` not change anything?

`ConfigureAwait` changes the behaviour of *`await`ing* a task. It determines whether the *continuation* (everything after the 'await' keyword') should run on the same synchronization context (the UI thread) or on any thread from the thread pool. In the following example, the second call to `StateHasChanged()` would be executed on a default thread from the thread pool (and would throw an exception):

```cs
awaitingRequest = true;
StateHasChanged();

await gPT.SendCommand("system", bot.Description, apiKey, true).ConfigureAwait(false);

StateHasChanged();
```

In your case, you aren't `await`ing the task so calling `ConfigureAwait` has no effect.

Comment: I guess `SendCommand` spawns a child Task that runs continuously, which takes over the UI sychronization context when you yield it and holds it for the duration of the command. That child task should be created with `ConfigureAwait(false)` to prevent this, but your workaround is the next best solution

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try that, but it didn't work. I'm guessing it could theoretically return to the UI thread even with ConfigureAwait(false) if the UI thread is free, which it could be whilst the Task.Delay is running. My understanding of ConfigureAwait(false) is that it allows the async method to return on *any* available thread (not just the context thread), whereas Task.Run will force the use of a new thread.

Comment: I mean call ConfigureAwait(false) _within_ gpt.SendCommand, not on the task returned by it. Your calling code definitely needs to return to the same synchronization context otherwise you might get an exception when trying to update the UI. I'll add a more detailed explanation to your answer

Comment: This looks like a case where `gPT.SendCommand` is a synchronous code block running inside a Task.  It's not  yielding as you expect.